# input field not behaving as expected while making atom plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, atom-editor

I'm newbie in making atom plugins. I have to make a field which will take an input. I'm using [etch](https://github.com/atom/etch) for component management. In the `render` method, I've made this input field

```
<input
    name={'component'}
    type={'text'}
    onchange={this.onInputChange}
    value={this.componentName}
/>
```

I've made this `onInputChange` method which looks like :

```
onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.componentName = event.target.value;

    etch.update(this);
  }
```

but I'm getting an event which comes after some time (kinda debounced event), furthermore I'm not able to delete the text from input. What is the right way to make an input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="native-key-bindings">
    <input/>
</div>
```

Try wrapping it in this way. It will also fix the delete issue.